# C# - Dynamic properties and RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, binding, dynamic-properties

I have following class which I use for radio button binding

```
public class RadioButtonSwitch : ViewModelBase
    {

        IDictionary<string, bool> _options;
        public RadioButtonSwitch(IDictionary<string, bool> options)
        {
            this._options = options;
        }

        public bool this[string a]
        {
            get
            {
                return _options[a];
            }
            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    var other = _options.Where(p => p.Key != a).Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
                    foreach (string key in other)
                        _options[key] = false;
                    _options[a] = true;

                    RaisePropertyChanged("XXXX");
                else
                    _options[a] = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<RadioButton Content="Day" IsChecked="{Binding RadioSwitch[radio1], Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="Monthly" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

ViewModel

```
RadioSwitch = new RadioButtonSwitch(
                new Dictionary<string, bool> {{"radio1", true},{"radio2", false}}
                );
```

**I'm having problem with RaisePropertyChanged() in my Class. I'm not sure what value I should be putting in order to raise the change.**

I tried putting:

- Item[]
- a
- [a]

I keep getting following error:

[image: Error]

This is so in case of any change I can handle it in my view accordingly. Please do not give me solutions for List for radio buttons etc.

Comment: Where is `ViewModelBase` defined?

Comment: `ViewModelBase` extends `GalaSoft.MvvMLight` `ViewModelBase`. It implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `RaisePropertyChanged` pretty much just calls `if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));`

Comment: Hmm, then where is the error *coming* from?  Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @KirkWoll added screenshot of the error. I'm assuming error is happening because I'm not calling RaisePropertyChanged() with correct parameter. `RadioButton` is binded to `[radio1]`, I tried using that as property name but it didnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are implementing an **indexer**, not an ordinary **property**.  Although the binding subsystem supports indexers, *MVVMLight* and `INotifyPropertyChanged` do not.

If you want to use an indexer you need to:

- Use a collection base class such as `ObservableCollection<T>`
- Implement `INotifiyCollectionChanged` and raise **that** event instead

The first option isn't realistic because you are already deriving from `ViewModelBase` and have to continue to do that.  Since implementing `INotifiyCollectionChanged` is a little bit of work, the easiest approach is to:

- add a property to `RadioButtonSwitch` that is an observable collection of boolean values (`ObservableCollection<bool>`)

Then change you binding to add one more path element and you are done.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment and rereading your question, I think implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` is the easiest.  Here is the rewrite of your `RadioButtonSwitch` class which actually no longer needs to derive from the *MVVMLight* base class, although you still could if you wanted to.

The careful reader will notice that we use a sledgehammer and "reset" the whole collection when any element of the collection is modified.  This is not just laziness; it is because the indexer uses a **string index** instead of an integer index and `INotifyCollectionChanged` doesn't support that.  As a result, when anything changes we just throw up our hands and say the whole collection has changed.

```
public class RadioButtonSwitch : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected void RaiseCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    IDictionary<string, bool> _options;
    public RadioButtonSwitch(IDictionary<string, bool> options)
    {
        this._options = options;
    }

    public bool this[string a]
    {
        get
        {
            return _options[a];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                var other = _options.Where(p => p.Key != a).Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
                foreach (string key in other)
                    _options[key] = false;
                _options[a] = true;

                RaiseCollectionChanged();
            }
            else
                _options[a] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Second option sounds good. However I'm don't know how to bind to a specific row of ObservableCollection. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Great that's exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 2):

GalaSoft.MvvmLight has the following code to check property name before raising `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    if (GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Property not found", propertyName);
}
```

`GetType().GetProperty("Item[]")` obviously returns null.
This is why it is failing.

I think, the quickest workaround for you would be not to use `ViewModelBase` from this library, but implement your own version, that doesn't do this check:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If you implement this class you will be able to run `RaisePropertyChanged("Item[]")`.

Comment: I wouldn't want to implement everything from scratch nor change existing methods used everywhere else.